# Python - Searching a dictionary for strings

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Basically, I have a troubleshooting program, which, I want the user to enter their input. Then, I take this input and split the words into separate strings. After that, I want to create a dictionary from the contents of a .CSV file, with the key as recognisable keywords and the second column as solutions. Finally, I want to check if any of the strings from the split users input are in the dictionary key, print the solution.

However, the problem I am facing is that I can do what I have stated above, however, it loops through and if my input was 'My phone is wet', and 'wet' was a recognisable keyword, it would go through and say 'Not recognised', 'Not recognised', 'Not recognised', then finally it would print the solution. It says not recognised so many times because the strings 'My', 'phone' and 'is' are not recognised.

So how do I test if a users split input is in my dictionary without it outputting 'Not recognised' etc..

Sorry if this was unclear, I'm quite confused by the whole matter.

Code:

```
import csv, easygui as eg
KeywordsCSV = dict(csv.reader(open('Keywords and Solutions.csv')))
Problem = eg.enterbox('Please enter your problem: ', 'Troubleshooting').lower().split()
for Problems, Solutions in (KeywordsCSV.items()):
    pass
```

Note, I have the pass there, because this is the part I need help on.

My CSV file consists of:

problemKeyword | solution

For example;

wet Put the phone in a bowl of rice.

Comment: Please post your code :)

Comment: Edited with the code included.

Comment: You didn't include the part where your code is breaking. Don't just put a `pass` because you know your code doesn't work there, allow us to see what you tried already

Comment: why use `if Problem in KeywordsCSV: ...` to test if it is in the dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reads like some ugly code golf. Let's clean it up before we look at how to solve the problem

```
import easygui as eg
import csv

# # KeywordsCSV = dict(csv.reader(open('Keywords and Solutions.csv')))
# why are you nesting THREE function calls? That's awful. Don't do that.
# KeywordsCSV should be named something different, too. `problems` is probably fine.

with open("Keywords and Solutions.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    problems = dict(reader)

problem = eg.enterbox('Please enter your problem: ', 'Troubleshooting').lower().split()
# this one's not bad, but I lowercased your `Problem` because capital-case
# words are idiomatically class names. Chaining this many functions together isn't
# ideal, but for this one-shot case it's not awful.
```

Let's break a second here and notice that I changed something on literally every line of your code. Take time to familiarize yourself with PEP8 when you can! It will drastically improve any code you write in Python.

Anyway, once you've got a `problems` dict, and a `problem` that should be a KEY in that dict, you can do:

```
if problem in problems:
    solution = problems[problem]
```

or even using the default return of `dict.get`:

```
solution = problems.get(problem)
# if KeyError: solution is None
```

If you wanted to loop this, you could do something like:

```
while True:
    problem = eg.enterbox(...)  # as above
    solution = problems.get(problem)
    if solution is None:
        # invalid problem, warn the user
    else:
        # display the solution? Do whatever it is you're doing with it and...
        break
```

Comment: Okay, so after reading through this and testing it using the while loop suggestion you said I could use, I got this error: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable. After researching a bit, I just couldn't find a solution which related to my type of code if you get what I mean.

Comment: I don't call any dicts, so you must not have copied my code correctly.

Comment: Okay, so after checking again, I deleted all of my code, and copied it exactly from here, and got this error :/     solution = problems.get(problem)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @Thom9son ah yes, you're getting a list because you're calling `str.split`. I don't know what `easygui.enterbox` returns. Do you mean to do `(...).lower().strip()`?

Comment: Would splitting the users input provide the same result as splitting it? Because I want to split it so that I can search for keywords, as you have helped me with.

Comment: @Thom9son then you'll have to iterate through the user's input, perhaps? Either way, it doesn't seem relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a boolean and an if after the loop that only runs if none of the words in the sentence were recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to use something like:

```
for word in Problem:
    if KeywordsCSV.has_key(word):
        KeywordsCSV.get(word)
```

or the list comprehension:

```
[KeywordsCSV.get(word) for word in Problem if KeywordsCSV.has_key(word)]
```

Comment: `dict.has_key` isn't in Python3, and shouldn't be used in Python2 either. Use `key in dict` instead of `dict.has_key(key)`

Comment: However if you're checking that it has the key, why use `dict.get`? Just use item access `KeywordsCSV[word]`

Comment: Did not know that about `has_key`. I've always assumed if the method was builtin, it's good to use. Same thing for `dict.get()`, I would assume builtin method would be better than using brackets

Comment: Nope. dict.get has some great uses, but if you know a key is there you should use item access.